# Add One to Integer Column Using Query in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I dont recall exactly how, but I do remember being able to add one to an integer column in mysql with a query without knowing the value of that integer column...

something like

```
update table set column=column+1 where id=1
```

I am wondering, how can I do the above query with CakePHP 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\Cake\ORM\Table::updateAll()` (or the underlying `\Cake\Database\Query::update()`), and use an expression to generate the arithmetic operation part, something like:

```
$additionExpression = $Table->query()->newExpr('column + 1');

$affectedRows = $Table->updateAll(
    ['column' => $additionExpression],
    ['id' => 1]
);
```

Or a little more complex in case you want to make use of automatic identifier quoting:

```
$additionExpression = $Table
    ->query()
    ->newExpr()
    ->add([
        new \Cake\Database\Expression\IdentifierExpression('column'),
        '1'
    ])
    ->setConjunction('+'); // tieWith() before CakePHP 3.4
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Bulk Updates](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Raw Expressions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions)**